# Unable to establish connection using socket.io

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, webrtc

```
`import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';


export default function App() {

  return (
    <HomeScreen />
  );
}`
```

this is my app.js in which I embedded homescreen component whose code is

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default function HomeScreen() {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const socket = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
       socket.current = io("http://localhost:3001");
      return () => {
        socket.disconnect();
      };
    }, []);
     
    const sendMessage = () => {
        socket.current.emit("message", message);
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>hello</Text>
        <TextInput value={message} onChangeText={text => setMessage(text)} placeholder="Enter chat message" onSubmitEditing={sendMessage} />
      </View>
    );
  }
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

the above frontend files are connected to server.js

```
const io = require("socket.io")();

io.on("conection", socket => {
    console.log("a user has connected");
    socket.on("message", message => {
        console.log(message);
    }
    );
})
io.listen(3001, function()
{
    console.log("listening on port 3001");
});
```

Iam expected to see a message when I send something via text area of homescreen atleast the conection establishment message like my instructor is able to see on his console. I found no errors in my console either on backend and frontend.

Comment: Is the spelling of the connection is right? in this line?  'io.on("conection", socket => {'  ?

There needs to be 2n's in connection

Comment: Thanks for identifying mistake. But still unable to establish connection.